# Capture large webpage screenshot in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, screenshot, webpage

The webpage is very large (a few MB). I tried these extensions and they all fail:

- **Screen Capture (by Google)** - I get a new tab with no image in it
- **Pixlr Grabber** - I get a "500" request error after pressing save
- **Capture Webpage Screenshot - Fireshot** - telling me that the webpage is too big and it will be saved to RAM, after which I get an error: `Insufficient video memory: You need at least -2365 MB of RAM` (that's ridiculous, and I have I like 1 GB)
- **Webpage & WebCam Screenshot** - I get no image
- **Awesome Screenshot - Capture & Annotate** - It says `capturing...`, and when finishes it open a new tab with some buttons. When I press "done" it says `preparing your image...` forever.

Do you know any website screen capture tools that actually work?

Comment: Could you give us the URL of the website you want to save? If it is a really huge page, it is possible that the capture process requires GBs of RAM. As you have only 1 GB it is possible that it would take a long time for the capturing to finish as instead of using RAM, swap space on the hard disk is used, which is very slow. Did you try to let Awesome Screenshot - Capture & Annotate run over night to see if it finally works or if it crashes?

Comment: it's a local page, Chrome metrics box shows a `1600 x 140000` page size. But the content has a lot of simple graphics and whitespace (~95% is just white or grey background). If compressed, the image shouldn't take more than a few MB

Comment: You state correctly IF compressed it should not take much space. But first the image will be in an uncompressed state which will take up GBs of space.

Comment: You sure its 1600 x 140000 because thats a GIGANTIC image.  Furthermore 2365 is more then 2GB so if you only have 1Gb that explains the error.

Comment: I just created a 1600x140000 image in photoshop instantly. It says image size: 649mb, and that's probably uncompressed. But for some reason it won't save in png or jpg format :|

Comment: Just to rescue Lunaar's link [with ~30.000px downwards](http://imgur.com/a/MdBfW). That's not as big as requested with 140.000px but it's a start

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved in Chrome as of v59:

[Announcement in the developer blog](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#screenshots)

[Video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_6_9eFPhxI)

Summary of steps (if you prefer text):

1. Open Developer tools
2. Toggle the device toolbar
3. Set the desired resolution in the device toolbar
4. Select the More options overflow menu in the device toolbar
5. Select Capture screenshot or Capture full size screenshot
6. The screenshot will be saved to your Downloads folder

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for the heads up. Will vote to close next time.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using chrome I would use [CutyCapt](https://github.com/hoehrmann/CutyCapt) it captures webkit's render to an image.

> CutyCapt is a small cross-platform command-line utility to capture
>   WebKit's rendering of a web page into a variety of vector and bitmap
>   formats, including SVG, PDF, PS, PNG, JPEG, TIFF, GIF, and BMP. See
>   IECapt for a similar tool based on Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using PhantomJS in windows, I used...

screenshot.js

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('http://gigantic-web-page.com', function () {
    page.render('test.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Dump this in your phantomjs folder, then one more file, screenshot.cmd

```
phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=yes --cookies-file=cookies.txt --web-security=no screenshot.js
```

With both of these files in your phantomjs folder, run screenshot.cmd... I just generated a 40mb png file of a gigantic page, it took a while and churned away but it finally output it!

Answer (score 0):

> Capture large webpage screenshot in Chrome? The webpage is very large (a few MB). I tried Screen Capture (by Google) - I get a new tab with no image in it

That’s because of quirks with the canvas element it uses. Ignore it and save the file, then open the file; it should be fine.

A while ago I got the empty-tab issue as well (seems to be somewhat common when using the *Caputre Whole Page* function), and on a lark, I clicked the `[Save]` button anyway. When I opened the resulting file (out of curiosity, thinking it would be either blank or 0x0), I was surprised to see the image was not only there, but *correct*! Nice.

Of course this means that you won’t be able to use the extension’s (limited) image-editing tools before saving, but so what? you can use MSPaint or whatever just as easily (I for one always save it without modification, then modify a copy).